# NLTK Named Entity recognition to a Python list

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I used NLTK's `ne_chunk` to extract named entities from a text:

```
my_sent = "WASHINGTON -- In the wake of a string of abuses by New York police officers in the 1990s, Loretta E. Lynch, the top federal prosecutor in Brooklyn, spoke forcefully about the pain of a broken trust that African-Americans felt and said the responsibility for repairing generations of miscommunication and mistrust fell to law enforcement."


nltk.ne_chunk(my_sent, binary=True)
```

But I can't figure out how to save these entities to a list? E.g. –

```
print Entity_list
('WASHINGTON', 'New York', 'Loretta', 'Brooklyn', 'African')
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `ne_chunk()` return instead? What exactly are you stuck at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named Entity Recognition with Regular Expression: NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398536/named-entity-recognition-with-regular-expression-nltk)

Comment: When I run your code I get an IndexError

Comment: This is a bit old, but you have to do something like `nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize("Welcome to Barbados, Tobdy!")))`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`nltk.ne_chunk` returns a nested `nltk.tree.Tree` object so you would have to traverse the `Tree` object to get to the NEs.

Take a look at [Named Entity Recognition with Regular Expression: NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398536/named-entity-recognition-with-regular-expression-nltk)

```
>>> from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.tree import Tree
>>> 
>>> def get_continuous_chunks(text):
...     chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
...     continuous_chunk = []
...     current_chunk = []
...     for i in chunked:
...             if type(i) == Tree:
...                     current_chunk.append(" ".join([token for token, pos in i.leaves()]))
...             if current_chunk:
...                     named_entity = " ".join(current_chunk)
...                     if named_entity not in continuous_chunk:
...                             continuous_chunk.append(named_entity)
...                             current_chunk = []
...             else:
...                     continue
...     return continuous_chunk
... 
>>> my_sent = "WASHINGTON -- In the wake of a string of abuses by New York police officers in the 1990s, Loretta E. Lynch, the top federal prosecutor in Brooklyn, spoke forcefully about the pain of a broken trust that African-Americans felt and said the responsibility for repairing generations of miscommunication and mistrust fell to law enforcement."
>>> get_continuous_chunks(my_sent)
['WASHINGTON', 'New York', 'Loretta E. Lynch', 'Brooklyn']


>>> my_sent = "How's the weather in New York and Brooklyn"
>>> get_continuous_chunks(my_sent)
['New York', 'Brooklyn']
```

Answer (score 22):

You can also extract the `label` of each Name Entity in the text using this code:

```
import nltk
for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence):
   for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
      if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
         print(chunk.label(), ' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk))
```

**Output:**

```
GPE WASHINGTON
GPE New York
PERSON Loretta E. Lynch
GPE Brooklyn
```

You can see `Washington`, `New York` and `Brooklyn` are `GPE` means **geo-political entities**

and `Loretta E. Lynch` is a `PERSON`

Comment: How can I save the output in a list or array, first column GPE etc. and second column Washington etc.

Comment: you can define a list of tuples. for example, on top of code add `lst=[]`
Then instead of print function at the last line, `lst.append((chunk.label(), chunk[0][0]))`

Answer (score 8):

As you get a [`tree`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html) as a return value, I guess you want to pick those subtrees that are labeled with `NE`

Here is a simple example to gather all those in a list:

```
import nltk

my_sent = "WASHINGTON -- In the wake of a string of abuses by New York police officers in the 1990s, Loretta E. Lynch, the top federal prosecutor in Brooklyn, spoke forcefully about the pain of a broken trust that African-Americans felt and said the responsibility for repairing generations of miscommunication and mistrust fell to law enforcement."

parse_tree = nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.tag.pos_tag(my_sent.split()), binary=True)  # POS tagging before chunking!

named_entities = []

for t in parse_tree.subtrees():
    if t.label() == 'NE':
        named_entities.append(t)
        # named_entities.append(list(t))  # if you want to save a list of tagged words instead of a tree

print named_entities
```

This gives:

```
[Tree('NE', [('WASHINGTON', 'NNP')]), Tree('NE', [('New', 'NNP'), ('York', 'NNP')])]
```

or as a list of lists:

```
[[('WASHINGTON', 'NNP')], [('New', 'NNP'), ('York', 'NNP')]]
```

Also see: [How to navigate a nltk.tree.Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841997/how-to-navigate-a-nltk-tree-tree)

Answer (score 6):

use tree2conlltags from nltk.chunk. Also ne_chunk needs pos tagging which tags word tokens (thus needs word_tokenize).

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.chunk import tree2conlltags

sentence = "Mark and John are working at Google."
print(tree2conlltags(ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
"""[('Mark', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), 
    ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('John', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), 
    ('are', 'VBP', 'O'), ('working', 'VBG', 'O'), 
    ('at', 'IN', 'O'), ('Google', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), 
    ('.', '.', 'O')] """
```

This will give you a list of tuples: [(token, pos_tag, name_entity_tag)]
If this list is not exactly what you want, it is certainly easier to parse the list you want out of this list then an nltk tree.

Code and details from [this link](http://nlpforhackers.io/named-entity-extraction/); check it out for more information

You can also continue by only extracting the words, with the following function:

```
def wordextractor(tuple1):

    #bring the tuple back to lists to work with it
    words, tags, pos = zip(*tuple1)
    words = list(words)
    pos = list(pos)
    c = list()
    i=0
    while i<= len(tuple1)-1:
        #get words with have pos B-PERSON or I-PERSON
        if pos[i] == 'B-PERSON':
            c = c+[words[i]]
        elif pos[i] == 'I-PERSON':
            c = c+[words[i]]
        i=i+1

    return c

print(wordextractor(tree2conlltags(nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))))
```

**Edit** Added output docstring
**Edit* Added Output only for B-Person

Answer (score 4):

You may also consider using Spacy:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc = nlp('WASHINGTON -- In the wake of a string of abuses by New York police officers in the 1990s, Loretta E. Lynch, the top federal prosecutor in Brooklyn, spoke forcefully about the pain of a broken trust that African-Americans felt and said the responsibility for repairing generations of miscommunication and mistrust fell to law enforcement.')

print([ent for ent in doc.ents])

>>> [WASHINGTON, New York, the 1990s, Loretta E. Lynch, Brooklyn, African-Americans]
```

Comment: I like clean solutions using list generators.  One can get labels too:  
print([(ent.label_, ent.text) for ent in doc.ents])

Answer (score 3):

A `Tree` is a list. Chunks are subtrees, non-chunked words are regular strings. So let's go down the list, extract the words from each chunk, and join them.

```
>>> chunked = nltk.ne_chunk(my_sent)
>>>
>>>  [ " ".join(w for w, t in elt) for elt in chunked if isinstance(elt, nltk.Tree) ]
['WASHINGTON', 'New York', 'Loretta E. Lynch', 'Brooklyn']
```

Answer (score 1):

nltk.ne_chunk returns a nested nltk.tree.Tree object so you would have to traverse the Tree object to get to the NEs. You can use list comprehension to do the same.

```
import nltk   
my_sent = "WASHINGTON -- In the wake of a string of abuses by New York police officers in the 1990s, Loretta E. Lynch, the top federal prosecutor in Brooklyn, spoke forcefully about the pain of a broken trust that African-Americans felt and said the responsibility for repairing generations of miscommunication and mistrust fell to law enforcement."

word = nltk.word_tokenize(my_sent)   
pos_tag = nltk.pos_tag(word)   
chunk = nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag)   
NE = [ " ".join(w for w, t in ele) for ele in chunk if isinstance(ele, nltk.Tree)]   
print (NE)
```