# Selecting and concatenating two (or more) strings based on NLTK-tags

Tags: nlp, nltk, list-comprehension

I have lists of NLTK-tags as below. I would like to select only those tagged as 'NNP' and, more specifically, first and last names (e.g. Event Chair Iris Dankner, Even Producer Barbara Schorr).

```
O5 = [[(u'Room', 'NN'), (u'Designers', 'NNS'), (u',', ','), (u'BCRF', 'NNP'), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'Holiday', 'NNP'), (u'House', 'NNP'), (u'staff', 'NN'), (u'cheer', 'NN'), (u'themselves', 'PRP'), (u'for', 'IN'), (u'a', 'DT'), (u'job', 'NN'), (u'well', 'RB'), (u'done', 'VBN')], [(u'Holiday', 'NNP'), (u'House', 'NNP'), (u'Founder', 'NNP'), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'Event', 'NNP'), (u'Chair', 'NNP'), (u'Iris', 'NNP'), (u'Dankner', 'NNP'), (u'with', 'IN'), (u'Event', 'NNP'), (u'Producer', 'NNP'), (u'Barbara', 'NNP'), (u'Schorr', 'NNP')], [(u'Architect', 'NNP'), (u'Joan', 'NNP'), (u'Dineen', 'NNP'), (u'with', 'IN'), (u'Alyson', 'NNP'), (u'Liss', 'NNP')]]
```

Here I tried

```
O5 = [O5[i][0] for O5[i][1] ==  "NNP"]
```

And

```
O5 = [O5[i][0] for O5[i][1] =  "NNP"]
```

Both produce `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Could anyone give me some suggestions here? Thank you!!

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31838373/610569

Comment: Thanks. I used the code you provided but gained some interesting (not exactly what I would like) results. You code is very nice, however. If you'd like to chat more, please let me know. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not recommended to name your list 05.

```
input = [[(u'Room', 'NN'), (u'Designers', 'NNS'), (u',', ','), (u'BCRF', 'NNP'), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'Holiday', 'NNP'), (u'House', 'NNP'), (u'staff', 'NN'), (u'cheer', 'NN'), (u'themselves', 'PRP'), (u'for', 'IN'), (u'a', 'DT'), (u'job', 'NN'), (u'well', 'RB'), (u'done', 'VBN')], [(u'Holiday', 'NNP'), (u'House', 'NNP'), (u'Founder', 'NNP'), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'Event', 'NNP'), (u'Chair', 'NNP'), (u'Iris', 'NNP'), (u'Dankner', 'NNP'), (u'with', 'IN'), (u'Event', 'NNP'), (u'Producer', 'NNP'), (u'Barbara', 'NNP'), (u'Schorr', 'NNP')], [(u'Architect', 'NNP'), (u'Joan', 'NNP'), (u'Dineen', 'NNP'), (u'with', 'IN'), (u'Alyson', 'NNP'), (u'Liss', 'NNP')]]
```

Then you can do list-comprehension like this

```
result = [token[0] for sent in input for token in sent if token[1] == 'NNP']
```

To make it more understandable you can use this

```
result = []
for sent in input:
    result = result + [token[0] for token in sent if token[1] == 'NNP']
```

If you would like to extract chunks (sequence of tokens) I recommend to use regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you. This seems a fast approach. As I ran this code, however, I received `[(u'Architect', 'NNP'),
 (u'Architect', 'NNP'),
 (u'Architect', 'NNP'),
 (u'Joan', 'NNP'),
 (u'Joan', 'NNP'),
 (u'Joan', 'NNP'),
 (u'Dineen', 'NNP'),
 (u'Dineen', 'NNP'),
 (u'Dineen', 'NNP'),
 (u'Alyson', 'NNP'),
 (u'Alyson', 'NNP'),
 (u'Alyson', 'NNP'),
 (u'Liss', 'NNP'),
 (u'Liss', 'NNP'),
 (u'Liss', 'NNP')]` It seems a result from the last list of tuples. Is there a way to get all of them?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I would love to extract chunks of sentences. Thank you for pointing out the use of regular expressions. I am reading that part. I shall highly appreciate if you have further suggestions on getting chunks of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have chunks of sentences that contain 'NNP' words, you could do the following:

```
# Input
inp = [[(u'Room', 'NN'), (u'Designers', 'NNS'), (u',', ','), (u'BCRF', 'NNP'), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'Holiday', 'NNP'), (u'House', 'NNP'), (u'staff', 'NN'), (u'cheer', 'NN'), (u'themselves', 'PRP'), (u'for', 'IN'), (u'a', 'DT'), (u'job', 'NN'), (u'well', 'RB'), (u'done', 'VBN')], [(u'Holiday', 'NNP'), (u'House', 'NNP'), (u'Founder', 'NNP'), (u'and', 'CC'), (u'Event', 'NNP'), (u'Chair', 'NNP'), (u'Iris', 'NNP'), (u'Dankner', 'NNP'), (u'with', 'IN'), (u'Event', 'NNP'), (u'Producer', 'NNP'), (u'Barbara', 'NNP'), (u'Schorr', 'NNP')], [(u'Architect', 'NNP'), (u'Joan', 'NNP'), (u'Dineen', 'NNP'), (u'with', 'IN'), (u'Alyson', 'NNP'), (u'Liss', 'NNP')]]

# Initialize list that will contain all chunks per sentence
lAllSents = []

# Loop through sentences
for sent in inp:
    # Initialize a list with all chunks for this sentence
    lSent = []

    # Initialize a list for the current chunk of 'NNP' words
    lChunk = []

    for token in sent:
        # If the word has the 'NNP' tag, append it to the chunk list
        if token[1] == 'NNP':
            lChunk.append(token)

        # If it has another tag, append the chunk list to the sentence list
        else:
            if lChunk:
                lSent.append(lChunk)
            lChunk = []

    # If the chunk still contains 'NNP' tokens, append those to the sentence list
    if lChunk:
            lSent.append(lChunk)

    # Append the sentence list to the list with all sentences
    lAllSents.append(lSent)
```

Now you have the following list, containing all the chunks per sentence:

```
[
    [
      [('BCRF', 'NNP')], [('Holiday', 'NNP'), ('House', 'NNP')]
    ],
    [
      [('Holiday', 'NNP'), ('House', 'NNP'), ('Founder', 'NNP')],
      [('Event', 'NNP'), ('Chair', 'NNP'), ('Iris', 'NNP'), ('Dankner', 'NNP')],
      [('Event', 'NNP'), ('Producer', 'NNP'), ('Barbara', 'NNP'), ('Schorr', 'NNP')]
    ],
    [
      [('Architect', 'NNP'), ('Joan', 'NNP'), ('Dineen', 'NNP')],
      [('Alyson', 'NNP'), ('Liss', 'NNP')]
    ]
]
```

**Notes**

- Do not give confusing names to your variables: `05` seems inappropriate. (Also do not use `input`, as [`input` is a Python function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output).)
- I would not recommend regular expressions for tasks that can be done with regexes: read [this post on StackOverflow why you shouldn't use them when not necessary](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions).