# NLTK relation extraction returns nothing

Tags: python, nltk, semantics, relation, knowledge-base-population

I am recently working on using nltk to extract relation from text. so i build a sample text:" Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft." and using following program to test and return nothing. I cannot figure out why.

I'm using NLTK version: 3.2.1, python version: 3.5.2.

Here is my code:

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.sem.relextract import extract_rels, rtuple
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize


def test():
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
        sample = f.read()   # "Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft"

    sentences = sent_tokenize(sample)
    tokenized_sentences = [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    tagged_sentences = [nltk.tag.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]

    OF = re.compile(r'.*\bof\b.*')

    for i, sent in enumerate(tagged_sentences):
        sent = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(sent) # ne_chunk method expects one tagged sentence
        rels = extract_rels('PER', 'GPE', sent, corpus='ace', pattern=OF, window=10) 
        for rel in rels:
            print('{0:<5}{1}'.format(i, rtuple(rel)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

---

### 1.　After some debug, if found that when i changed the input as

> "Gates was born in Seattle, Washington on October 28, 1955. "

### the nltk.chunk.ne_chunk() output is:

> (S
>     (PERSON Gates/NNS)
>     was/VBD
>     born/VBN
>     in/IN
>     (GPE Seattle/NNP)
>     ,/,
>     (GPE Washington/NNP)
>     on/IN
>     October/NNP
>     28/CD
>     ,/,
>     1955/CD
>     ./.)

### The test() returns:

> [PER: 'Gates/NNS'] 'was/VBD born/VBN in/IN' [GPE: 'Seattle/NNP']

### 2. After i changed the input as:

> "Gates was born in Seattle on October 28, 1955. "

The test() retuns nothing.

### 3. I digged into **nltk/sem/relextract.py** and find this strange

output is caused by function:
**semi_rel2reldict(pairs, window=5, trace=False), which returns result only when len(pairs) > 2, and that's why when one sentence with less than three NEs will return None.**

**Is this a bug or i used NLTK in wrong way?**

Comment: "pairs" in `semi_rel2reldict` don't necessary need to be NEs. Check `tree2semi_rel` also in relextract. Dig deeper, you'll find out why =)

Comment: BTW, use the `'PERSON'` and `'ORGANIZATION'` for your NE classes instead of 'PER' and 'ORG' because ACE classes are https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L30

Comment: Also, your sentence has no ORGANZATION when you NE tagged it, so your pattern won't match.

Comment: @alvas, sorry, "ORG" should be changed to "GPE", but the problem is sitll exists. If the sentence contains less than three NEs, extract_rels() won't return any result.

Comment: yes yes, you're on the right track. dig deeper. Look at the `tree2semi_rel` and try to understand what it does =) Also, "PER" may match nothing because the `ne_chunk` trained with ACE label is "PERSON" see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L30

Comment: @alvas, 'PER' will be replaced to 'PERSON' in relextract.py, so this is not the reason.

Comment: No worries about that, it's just for clarity sake, use the same labels as your tagger. Look at `tree2semi_rel` ! What is happening in that function? What does it return? Why does it returns what it returns?

Comment: @alvas, when the input sentence contains two NEs, `tree2semi_rel` will return a list of pairs (list(str), ``Tree``) with length 2, then `semi_rel2reldict` will return result with the condition `while len(pairs) > 2:`. So this method will not used to extract relations with two NEs?

Comment: Yes now, that's a good question to answer =)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply!

Comment: Good job on digging deeper! Check out the answer.  I hope it'll help you =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, to chunk NEs with `ne_chunk`, the idiom would look something like this

```
>>> from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> text = "Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft"
>>> chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
>>> chunked
Tree('S', [Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')])])
```

(see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31838373/610569)

Next let's look at the [`extract_rels` function](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L176).

```
def extract_rels(subjclass, objclass, doc, corpus='ace', pattern=None, window=10):
    """
    Filter the output of ``semi_rel2reldict`` according to specified NE classes and a filler pattern.
    The parameters ``subjclass`` and ``objclass`` can be used to restrict the
    Named Entities to particular types (any of 'LOCATION', 'ORGANIZATION',
    'PERSON', 'DURATION', 'DATE', 'CARDINAL', 'PERCENT', 'MONEY', 'MEASURE').
    """
```

When you evoke this function:

```
extract_rels('PER', 'GPE', sent, corpus='ace', pattern=OF, window=10)
```

It performs 4 processes sequentially.

## 1. It checks whether your `subjclass` and `objclass`are valid

i.e. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L202 :

```
if subjclass and subjclass not in NE_CLASSES[corpus]:
    if _expand(subjclass) in NE_CLASSES[corpus]:
        subjclass = _expand(subjclass)
    else:
        raise ValueError("your value for the subject type has not been recognized: %s" % subjclass)
if objclass and objclass not in NE_CLASSES[corpus]:
    if _expand(objclass) in NE_CLASSES[corpus]:
        objclass = _expand(objclass)
    else:
        raise ValueError("your value for the object type has not been recognized: %s" % objclass)
```

## 2. It extracts "pairs" from your NE tagged inputs:

```
if corpus == 'ace' or corpus == 'conll2002':
    pairs = tree2semi_rel(doc)
elif corpus == 'ieer':
    pairs = tree2semi_rel(doc.text) + tree2semi_rel(doc.headline)
else:
    raise ValueError("corpus type not recognized")
```

Now let's see given your input sentence `Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft`, what does `tree2semi_rel()` returns:

```
>>> from nltk.sem.relextract import tree2semi_rel, semi_rel2reldict
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> text = "Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft"
>>> chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
>>> tree2semi_rel(chunked)
[[[], Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')])], [[('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')], Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')])]]
```

So it returns a list of 2 lists, the first inner list consist of a blank list and the `Tree` that contains the "PERSON" tag.

```
[[], Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')])]
```

The second list consist of the phrase `is the cofounder of` and the `Tree` that contains "ORGANIZATION".

Let's move on.

## 3. `extract_rel` then tries to change the pairs to some sort of relation dictionary

```
reldicts = semi_rel2reldict(pairs)
```

If we look what the `semi_rel2reldict` function returns with your example sentence, we see that this is where the empty list gets returns:

```
>>> tree2semi_rel(chunked)
[[[], Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')])], [[('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')], Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')])]]
>>> semi_rel2reldict(tree2semi_rel(chunked))
[]
```

So let's look into the code of `semi_rel2reldict` https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L144:

```
def semi_rel2reldict(pairs, window=5, trace=False):
    """
    Converts the pairs generated by ``tree2semi_rel`` into a 'reldict': a dictionary which
    stores information about the subject and object NEs plus the filler between them.
    Additionally, a left and right context of length =< window are captured (within
    a given input sentence).
    :param pairs: a pair of list(str) and ``Tree``, as generated by
    :param window: a threshold for the number of items to include in the left and right context
    :type window: int
    :return: 'relation' dictionaries whose keys are 'lcon', 'subjclass', 'subjtext', 'subjsym', 'filler', objclass', objtext', 'objsym' and 'rcon'
    :rtype: list(defaultdict)
    """
    result = []
    while len(pairs) > 2:
        reldict = defaultdict(str)
        reldict['lcon'] = _join(pairs[0][0][-window:])
        reldict['subjclass'] = pairs[0][1].label()
        reldict['subjtext'] = _join(pairs[0][1].leaves())
        reldict['subjsym'] = list2sym(pairs[0][1].leaves())
        reldict['filler'] = _join(pairs[1][0])
        reldict['untagged_filler'] = _join(pairs[1][0], untag=True)
        reldict['objclass'] = pairs[1][1].label()
        reldict['objtext'] = _join(pairs[1][1].leaves())
        reldict['objsym'] = list2sym(pairs[1][1].leaves())
        reldict['rcon'] = _join(pairs[2][0][:window])
        if trace:
            print("(%s(%s, %s)" % (reldict['untagged_filler'], reldict['subjclass'], reldict['objclass']))
        result.append(reldict)
        pairs = pairs[1:]
    return result
```

The first thing that `semi_rel2reldict()` does is to check where there are more than 2 elements the output from `tree2semi_rel()`, which your example sentence doesn't:

```
>>> tree2semi_rel(chunked)
[[[], Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')])], [[('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')], Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')])]]
>>> len(tree2semi_rel(chunked))
2
>>> len(tree2semi_rel(chunked)) > 2
False
```

Ah ha, that's why the `extract_rel` is returning nothing.

**Now comes the question of how to make `extract_rel()` return something even with 2 elements from `tree2semi_rel()`?** Is that even possible?

Let's try a different sentence:

```
>>> text = "Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft and now he is the founder of Marcohard"
>>> chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
>>> chunked
Tree('S', [Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')]), ('and', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('he', 'PRP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('founder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), Tree('PERSON', [('Marcohard', 'NNP')])])
>>> tree2semi_rel(chunked)
[[[], Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')])], [[('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')], Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')])], [[('and', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('he', 'PRP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('founder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')], Tree('PERSON', [('Marcohard', 'NNP')])]]
>>> len(tree2semi_rel(chunked)) > 2
True
>>> semi_rel2reldict(tree2semi_rel(chunked))
[defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'lcon': '', 'untagged_filler': 'is the cofounder of', 'filler': 'is/VBZ the/DT cofounder/NN of/IN', 'objsym': 'microsoft', 'objclass': 'ORGANIZATION', 'objtext': 'Microsoft/NNP', 'subjsym': 'tom', 'subjclass': 'PERSON', 'rcon': 'and/CC now/RB he/PRP is/VBZ the/DT', 'subjtext': 'Tom/NNP'})]
```

**But that only confirms that `extract_rel` can't extract when `tree2semi_rel` returns pairs of < 2. What happens if we remove that condition of `while len(pairs) > 2`?**

Why can't we do `while len(pairs) > 1`?

If we look closer into the code, we see the last line of populating the reldict, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L169:

```
reldict['rcon'] = _join(pairs[2][0][:window])
```

It tries to access a 3rd element of the `pairs` and if the length of the `pairs` is 2, you'll get an `IndexError`.

**So what happens if we remove that `rcon` key and simply change it to `while len(pairs) >= 2`?**

To do that we have to override the `semi_rel2redict()` function:

```
>>> from nltk.sem.relextract import _join, list2sym
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def semi_rel2reldict(pairs, window=5, trace=False):
...     """
...     Converts the pairs generated by ``tree2semi_rel`` into a 'reldict': a dictionary which
...     stores information about the subject and object NEs plus the filler between them.
...     Additionally, a left and right context of length =< window are captured (within
...     a given input sentence).
...     :param pairs: a pair of list(str) and ``Tree``, as generated by
...     :param window: a threshold for the number of items to include in the left and right context
...     :type window: int
...     :return: 'relation' dictionaries whose keys are 'lcon', 'subjclass', 'subjtext', 'subjsym', 'filler', objclass', objtext', 'objsym' and 'rcon'
...     :rtype: list(defaultdict)
...     """
...     result = []
...     while len(pairs) >= 2:
...         reldict = defaultdict(str)
...         reldict['lcon'] = _join(pairs[0][0][-window:])
...         reldict['subjclass'] = pairs[0][1].label()
...         reldict['subjtext'] = _join(pairs[0][1].leaves())
...         reldict['subjsym'] = list2sym(pairs[0][1].leaves())
...         reldict['filler'] = _join(pairs[1][0])
...         reldict['untagged_filler'] = _join(pairs[1][0], untag=True)
...         reldict['objclass'] = pairs[1][1].label()
...         reldict['objtext'] = _join(pairs[1][1].leaves())
...         reldict['objsym'] = list2sym(pairs[1][1].leaves())
...         reldict['rcon'] = []
...         if trace:
...             print("(%s(%s, %s)" % (reldict['untagged_filler'], reldict['subjclass'], reldict['objclass']))
...         result.append(reldict)
...         pairs = pairs[1:]
...     return result
... 
>>> text = "Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft"
>>> chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
>>> tree2semi_rel(chunked)
[[[], Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')])], [[('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')], Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')])]]
>>> semi_rel2reldict(tree2semi_rel(chunked))
[defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'lcon': '', 'untagged_filler': 'is the cofounder of', 'filler': 'is/VBZ the/DT cofounder/NN of/IN', 'objsym': 'microsoft', 'objclass': 'ORGANIZATION', 'objtext': 'Microsoft/NNP', 'subjsym': 'tom', 'subjclass': 'PERSON', 'rcon': [], 'subjtext': 'Tom/NNP'})]
```

Ah! It works but there's still a 4th step in `extract_rels()`.

## 4. It performs a filter of the reldict given the regex you have provided to the `pattern` parameter, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L222:

```
relfilter = lambda x: (x['subjclass'] == subjclass and
                       len(x['filler'].split()) <= window and
                       pattern.match(x['filler']) and
                       x['objclass'] == objclass)
```

Now let's try it with the hacked version of `semi_rel2reldict`:

```
>>> text = "Tom is the cofounder of Microsoft"
>>> chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
>>> tree2semi_rel(chunked)
[[[], Tree('PERSON', [('Tom', 'NNP')])], [[('is', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('cofounder', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN')], Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Microsoft', 'NNP')])]]
>>> semi_rel2reldict(tree2semi_rel(chunked))
[defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'lcon': '', 'untagged_filler': 'is the cofounder of', 'filler': 'is/VBZ the/DT cofounder/NN of/IN', 'objsym': 'microsoft', 'objclass': 'ORGANIZATION', 'objtext': 'Microsoft/NNP', 'subjsym': 'tom', 'subjclass': 'PERSON', 'rcon': [], 'subjtext': 'Tom/NNP'})]
>>> 
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'.*\bof\b.*')
>>> reldicts = semi_rel2reldict(tree2semi_rel(chunked))
>>> relfilter = lambda x: (x['subjclass'] == subjclass and
...                            len(x['filler'].split()) <= window and
...                            pattern.match(x['filler']) and
...                            x['objclass'] == objclass)
>>> relfilter
<function <lambda> at 0x112e591b8>
>>> subjclass = 'PERSON'
>>> objclass = 'ORGANIZATION'
>>> window = 5
>>> list(filter(relfilter, reldicts))
[defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'lcon': '', 'untagged_filler': 'is the cofounder of', 'filler': 'is/VBZ the/DT cofounder/NN of/IN', 'objsym': 'microsoft', 'objclass': 'ORGANIZATION', 'objtext': 'Microsoft/NNP', 'subjsym': 'tom', 'subjclass': 'PERSON', 'rcon': [], 'subjtext': 'Tom/NNP'})]
```

It works! Now let's see it in tuple form:

```
>>> from nltk.sem.relextract import rtuple
>>> rels = list(filter(relfilter, reldicts))
>>> for rel in rels:
...     print rtuple(rel)
... 
[PER: 'Tom/NNP'] 'is/VBZ the/DT cofounder/NN of/IN' [ORG: 'Microsoft/NNP']
```

Comment: Thank you alvas for your great answer!

Comment: how can i get a result with multiple subclasses and objclasses ?