# ne_chunk without pos_tag in NLTK

Tags: python, tree, tags, nltk, chunking

I'm trying to chunk a sentence using ne_chunk and pos_tag in nltk.

```
from nltk import tag
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tree import Tree
from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk

sentence = "Michael and John is reading a booklet in a library of Jakarta"
tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())

print_chunk = [chunk for chunk in ne_chunk(tagged_sent) if isinstance(chunk, Tree)]

print print_chunk
```

and this is the result:

```
[Tree('GPE', [('Michael', 'NNP')]), Tree('PERSON', [('John', 'NNP')]), Tree('GPE', [('Jakarta', 'NNP')])]
```

my question, is it possible not to include pos_tag (like NNP above) and only include Tree 'GPE','PERSON'?
and what 'GPE' means?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The named entity chunker will give you a tree containing both chunks and tags. You can't change that, but you can take the tags out. Starting from your `tagged_sent`:

```
chunks = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged_sent)
simple = []
for elt in chunks:
    if isinstance(elt, Tree):
        simple.append(Tree(elt.label(), [ word for word, tag in elt ]))
    else:
        simple.append( elt[0] )
```

If you only want the chunks, omit the `else:` clause in the above. You can adapt the code to wrap the chunks any way you want. I used an nltk `Tree` to keep the changes to a minimum. Note that some chunks consist of multiple words (try adding "New York" to your example), so the chunk's contents must be a list, not a single element.

PS. "GPE" stands for "geo-political entity" (obviously a chunker mistake). You can see a list of the "commonly used tags" in the nltk book, [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#tab-ne-types).

Comment: Thanks it works! but how can I train some special NE ? like Michael must be 'PERSON' instead of 'GPE' because it's a person name.

Comment: Read the nltk book. Then ask a new question here if you are still wondering. Short answer, you could add a dictionary of person names to override the statistical cues, but in general there's not much you can do. You try to hand-fix too much, you break more than you fixed. (E.g. is "Elizabeth" the person or the city in New Jersey?.)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably a slight modification to the code on https://stackoverflow.com/a/31838373/610569 with the tags is what you require.

> is it possible not to include pos_tag (like NNP above) and only include Tree 'GPE','PERSON'?

Yes, simply traverse the Tree object =) See [How to Traverse an NLTK Tree object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689621/how-to-traverse-an-nltk-tree-object)

```
>>> from nltk import Tree, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> sentence = "Michael and John is reading a booklet in a library of Jakarta"
>>> tagged_sent = ne_chunk(pos_tag(sentence.split()))
>>> tagged_sent
Tree('S', [Tree('GPE', [('Michael', 'NNP')]), ('and', 'CC'), Tree('PERSON', [('John', 'NNP')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('reading', 'VBG'), ('a', 'DT'), ('booklet', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('library', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), Tree('GPE', [('Jakarta', 'NNP')])])

>>> from nltk.sem.relextract import NE_CLASSES
>>> ace_tags = NE_CLASSES['ace']

>>> for node in tagged_sent:
...     if type(node) == Tree and node.label() in ace_tags:
...         words, tags = zip(*node.leaves())
...         print node.label() + '\t' +  ' '.join(words)
... 
GPE Michael
PERSON  John
GPE Jakarta
```

---

> What 'GPE' means?

**GPE means "Geo-Political Entity"**

- The `GPE` tag came from the [ACE dataset](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/collaborations/past-projects/ace)
- There are two pre-trained NE chunkers available, see [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/chunk/**init**.py#L164](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/chunk/__init__.py#L164)
- There are 3 tag sets that are supported: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/sem/relextract.py#L31
- For a detailed explanation, see [NLTK relation extraction returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480839/nltk-relation-extraction-returns-nothing)