# Python 3 NLTK How to Perform Operations on the type 'nltk.tree.Tree' Chunk Extraction

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Let me preface this question by saying that I may not be using the correct datatype for the type of operation that I want, so I am open to any answer.

I am processing some text using NLTK and I am particularly interested in extracting text if it meets a certain chunking condition.

If the text meets the condition of the chunk I would like to extract it into a separate list or similar datatype as a string.

Here is my code:

```
 import nltk

 from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize



 def tokenize():
     sent_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer()
     tokenized = sent_tokenizer.tokenize('I went to the store.')
     return  tokenized

 def chunking():
     for i in (tokenize()):
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    chunkGram =r"""CHUNK: {<PRP><VBD><TO><DT><NN>}"""
    chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)
    chunked = chunkParser.parse(tagged)
    print(type(chunked))
    print(chunked)

 chunking()
```

In this example, I know that I am simply printing the text, but I want to the store matches the chunk gram perfectly. However, I cannot seem to do any operations on the matches and their type is of 'nltk.tree.Tree'. I have looked at some other questions on here but they seem to be more advanced for what I am trying to do. There must be some way to manipulate the tree or extract chunks.

I read some of the documentation of 'nltk.tree.Tree', and its pretty complicated and covers areas that I do not want to do yet.

The end goal is to loop though a bunch of text for chunks and if I find them output them to a list as a string (without the POS tag).

```
 extracted_by_chunking = ['I went to the store.', 'etc', 'etc']
```

So far I am able to pinpoint the information I need using chunking but I just cannot extract it. The task seems pretty straightforward, but I not sure where to go from here, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44237087/699305), the answer does exactly what you ask. Perhaps you'll want to add conversion of the chunk lists to strings (with `" ".join()`).

Comment: PS a `Tree` is a kind of list, so you can do anything to a `Tree` that you can do with a list (depending on its elements).

Comment: Whoops sorry if duplicate. Ill take a look at this today! Thanks!

Comment: Yo bro it works how do I give you props? Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, and I appreciate the thanks. Please upvote the duplicate question and the answer you used, that's the recommended way of showing appreciation on this site. (As it happens, one of the answers is mine.)