# What kind of NLP is this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I know that NLP Categorization is when we classify the whole text as (Health, Sports, Social, Business, etc.)

> (LONDON) -- Rafael Nadal offered a pointed criticism of All-England
>   Club's unique seeding rules on Saturday, two days before the start of
>   Wimbledon.
>
> "I respect the Wimbledon rules," Nadal told reporters, "...If I
>   believe that is fair or not, that's another story. I really personally
>   believe [it] is not."
>
> Wimbledon uses a special formula to develop the seedings for the
>   tournament, which sometimes depart from standard ATP rankings. The
>   formula gives extra weight to a player's ATP record on grass courts,
>   elevating or penalizing players who play less often or have less
>   success on grass.
>
> This year, the Wimbledon rankings bumped Nadal down to the
>   tournament's third seed, with Roger Federer hopping above him. That
>   would require Nadal to beat both players seeded above him to win the
>   title. It also sets up the possibility of a matchup with Nik Kyrgios
>   in the second round.
>
> Kyrgios has defeated Nadal at this tournament before.
>
> "The system is the way it is," Federer said at his own press
>   conference. "At the end of the day, if you want to win the tournament,
>   you got to go through all the players that are in front of you."
>
> Copyright © 2019, ABC Radio. All rights reserved.

This will be considered as "Sports" text

But this not what I want

I want to identify words or multiple words in the text

like in the text above if I want to Identify players

> (LONDON) -- ***Rafael Nadal*** offered a pointed criticism of All-England
>   Club's unique seeding rules on Saturday, two days before the start of
>   Wimbledon.
>
> "I respect the Wimbledon rules," ***Nadal*** told reporters, "...If I
>   believe that is fair or not, that's another story. I really personally
>   believe [it] is not."
>
> Wimbledon uses a special formula to develop the seedings for the
>   tournament, which sometimes depart from standard ATP rankings. The
>   formula gives extra weight to a player's ATP record on grass courts,
>   elevating or penalizing players who play less often or have less
>   success on grass.
>
> This year, the Wimbledon rankings bumped ***Nadal*** down to the
>   tournament's third seed, with ***Roger Federer*** hopping above him. That
>   would require ***Nadal*** to beat both players seeded above him to win the
>   title. It also sets up the possibility of a matchup with ***Nik Kyrgios***
>   in the second round.
>
> ***Kyrgios*** has defeated ***Nadal*** at this tournament before.
>
> "The system is the way it is," ***Federer*** said at his own press
>   conference. "At the end of the day, if you want to win the tournament,
>   you got to go through all the players that are in front of you."
>
> Copyright © 2019, ABC Radio. All rights reserved.

What is this method called and is there any python libraries specified for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to identify the names, persons in this text? This is called NER - Named Entitiy Recognotion.

You can use the famous `nltk` library if you want to analyze it: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html ,

[NLTK Named Entity recognition to a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836058/nltk-named-entity-recognition-to-a-python-list)

https://www.nltk.org/

Comment: can NEB classify a name, i mean if text says "Kyrgios played, also Federer played, but not Nadal". will it be able to identify the negation before Nadal si the results be Kyrgios positive, Federer positive, Nadal negative.

Answer (score 1):

This comes under the category of named entity recognition(NER). You can use NLTK and spacy for this. Tools like RASA NLU also make it possible for you to train a model to recognise these entities.

Here are some links that might be useful:
https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/entity-extractio

Answer (score 1):

This is a named entity extraction problem. You can use NLTK, Spacy, Stanford core NLP libraries for Named Entity Recognition.