# How to get sentence after chunking in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a sentence as follow:

```
txt =  "i am living in the West Bengal and my brother live in New York. My name is John Smith"
```

What I need is:

1. Get the Chunks With GPE/location as labels and combine these chunks using "_"
2. Get the Chunks With PERSON label and remove those chunks.

Output I needed:

```
preprocessed_txt =  "i am living in the West_Bengal and my brother live in New_York. My name is "
```

I use code from [NLTK Named Entity recognition to a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836058/nltk-named-entity-recognition-to-a-python-list/31837224#31837224) to get the labels of the chunks.

```
import nltk
for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence):
   for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
      if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
         print(chunk.label(), '_'.join(c[0] for c in chunk))
```

This returned me the output as:

```
LOCATION West_Bengal
GPE New_York
PERSON John_Smith
```

**What to do next?**

Comment: Try `'_'.join(c[0] for c in chunk))`

Comment: this gives the output as:                                                       
LOCATION West_Bengal
GPE New_York
PERSON John_Smith

Comment: You'd have to re-code, catching the tokens in a list then extract the names and replace them with original names in the list of tokens

Comment: @YashvanderBamel... How to do this? and this is what my question is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
new = list()
for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(tokens)):
  try:
    if chunk.label().lower() == 'person':
      continue
    else:
      new.append('_'.join(c[0] for c in chunk))

  except AttributeError:
    new.append(chunk[0])

print(' '.join(new))
```